# How to implement Readers Writers using multiple writers and multiple readers

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

The following code is written to get integers from file to buffer and to read them from the buffer. There are two writer threads which read the integer from file to buffer and two reader threads which read integers from the buffer. The buffer size is 5 and there may be any number of integers on the file. Writer threads must write all the integers on the file to the buffer and reader threads must read all the integers in the file via the buffer. Readers don't have direct access to the file. Since the buffer size is 5, when writers write data to the buffer and it gets full I have placed a `pthread_cond_signal(&r)` to inform the reader that it should start reading. But the readers keep printing zeros without terminating. I commented out readers part and writers part worked but it didn't print the 1st integer of the file and both the two writer threads read the final integer. (writer thread one read 100, writer thread 2 read 100. So buffer contains two 100s)Can someone please point me out the error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 5


pthread_mutex_t m;
pthread_cond_t  r;
pthread_cond_t w;
FILE *fp;

int cnt_r= 0;
int flag =0;
int value;
int buf[BUF_SIZE];
int cnt = 0;
int z = 0;



void *read(void *parm);
void *write(void *parm);

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{

    pthread_t rid[2];
    pthread_t wid[2];

    pthread_cond_init(&r,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&w,NULL);


    if ((fp = fopen("/home/bhagi/2/shared_data.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find the file");


    for( int i = 0; i< 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Writer %d Starts \n",i+1);
        pthread_create(&wid[i], NULL, write,i);
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Reader %d Starts \n",i+1);
        pthread_create(&rid[i],NULL,read,i);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(rid[i],NULL);
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(wid[i], NULL);
    }

    fclose(fp);


    return 0;
}

void *read(void *parm)
{

    int y = (int)parm;
    int cnt_r = 0;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);

        while (cnt == -1)
        {
            printf("Reader %d waits \n",y+1);
            pthread_cond_wait(&r, &m);
        }
        cnt++;

    printf("Reader %d Access CS\n",y+1);
     while(flag != -1)
     {
         for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++)
         {
             printf("%d ",buf[i]);
             cnt_r++;
             sleep(1);

         }
     printf("\n %d \n",cnt_r);
     }


     cnt--;
     if(cnt == 0)
        pthread_cond_signal(&w);

    if(cnt_r != 0)
    {
        pthread_cond_signal(&r);
        printf("Reader %d Signal Reader\n",y +1);
    }
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);



}

void *write(void *parm)
{

    int x = (int)parm;
    int cnt_w = 0;

    while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&value) == 1)
    {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
        while(cnt!= 0) {
            printf("Writer %d waits \n", x + 1);
            pthread_cond_wait(&w, &m);
        }
        cnt++;

        printf("Writer %d access cs \n",x+1);
        cnt = 0;
        pthread_cond_signal(&w);


        if(z == 5)
        {
            z = 0;
            pthread_cond_signal(&r);


        }

        buf[z] = value;
        printf("buf = %d\n",buf[z]);
        ++z;
        cnt_w++;


        sleep(1);
        printf("%d\n",cnt_w);



        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);


    }

    flag = -1;

}
```

Comment: Why do the readers have to wait until the buffer is full?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I can't figure out a way to inform the reader threads that they have read all the data in the file. Because getting data from file to buffer is done by writer threads. So I decided to inform reader once the buffer is full.

Comment: The code is pretty awful, so I'd recommend rewriting it entirely. That said, remember to enable and heed your compiler's warnings. Code like `cnt++;
        printf("Writer %d access cs \n",x+1);
        cnt = 0;` does not inspire confidence.

Answer (score 0):

*Since the buffer size is 5, when writers write data to the buffer and it gets full I have placed a `pthread_cond_signal(&r)`*

This has things backwards.  The general multiple reader-writer pattern is:

- the writer(s) wait until the buffer is *not* full, then write as much as they can, then signal a reader;
- the reader(s) wait until the buffer is *not* empty, then read as much as they can, then signal a writer.

You will need to augment this so that your readers know when to exit:

- the writer(s) wait until the buffer is *not* full, then write as much as they can, then signal a reader.  If a writer reaches EOF, it sets an end-of-file flag and signals **all** readers;
- the reader(s) wait until the buffer is *not* empty or the end-of-file flag is set.  In the case that the buffer is not empty, they then read as much as they can, then signal a writer; in the case where the end-of-file flag is set, they exit.

---

In terms of specific problems in your current code, two that stand out to me are:

- `flag` is accessed by the writers without the mutex held (this could be the cause of your infinite loop in the readers, since the compiler can assume that `flag` is never changed while the reader holds the mutex);
- `value` should be a local variable in the writers, but it is shared (and accessed unsychronised) - this is likely the cause of your writers both seeing the same number from the file.